# JSON error: " Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'"

Tags: json, validation

EDIT: I changed the single-quotes to double-quotes and the linters don't complain.

I put this into jsonlint.com and I got this error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   'bandwidth_in': {       
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

Similar results for other json linters. Originally, the numeric values were bare, so I wrapped those in single quotes to get rid of the `jq` error:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 16
```

But I still get that for jq.

I don't see any undefined keys, what am I missing?

```
{
    'bandwidth_in': {
        'GE4': {
            'value': '16292',
            'tree': {
                '2': {
                    'name': 'GE4',
                    'key': 'GE4',
                    'attributes': {
                        'snmp_index': 'GE4'
                    }
                }
            },
            'attributes': {
                'bandwidth': '15157250.0'
            }
        }
    },
    'bandwidth_out': {
        'GE4': {
            'value': '14616',
            'tree': {
                '2': {
                    'name': 'GE4',
                    'key': 'GE4',
                    'attributes': {
                        'snmp_index': 'GE4'
                    }
                }
            },
            'attributes': {
                'bandwidth': '15150500.0'
            }
        }
    },
    'jitter_in': {
        'GE4': {
            'value': '0.0',
            'tree': {
                '2': {
                    'name': 'GE4',
                    'key': 'GE4'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'jitter_out': {
        'GE4': {
            'value': '0.002',
            'tree': {
                '2': {
                    'name': 'GE4',
                    'key': 'GE4'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'latency_in': {
        'GE4': {
            'value': '0.001',
            'tree': {
                '2': {
                    'name': 'GE4',
                    'key': 'GE4'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'latency_out': {
        'GE4': {
            'value': '0.003',
            'tree': {
                '2': {
                    'name': 'GE4',
                    'key': 'GE4'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'packetloss_in': {
        'GE4': {
            'value': '0',
            'tree': {
                '2': {
                    'name': 'GE4',
                    'key': 'GE4'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    'packetloss_out': {
        'GE4': {
            'value': '0',
            'tree': {
                '2': {
                    'name': 'GE4',
                    'key': 'GE4'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also saw a reference online that bare numbers for keys aren't allowed, would it be fair to say that any JSON with non-string keys should not pass muster?

Comment: Your EDIT should have been [posted as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) instead. In any case, if you read the [JSON spec](https://www.json.org), strings don't support single-quotes as delimiters, only double-quotes. And keys must be strings.

Answer (score 0):

As Remy Labeau stated

> strings don't support single-quotes as delimiters, only double-quotes.

When you have a String containing inline JSON, you have some options:

**outter double quotes and inner escaped double quotes**

sJson = "{\"key\":\"value\"}"

**outer single quotes**

sJson = '{"key":"value"}'